# Drawing Tournament Brackets

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have have written some software that produces the draw for a tournament the problem i have is how to display the draw on a website. Are there any open source libraries that can draw tournament brackets in the right places and the line feeding to the next match in the tournament ? If not can someone recomend a way  to do this myself.
I am using c# and asp.net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tournament Brackets algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294412/tournament-brackets-algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you explored using [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/index.html), I've used it to create org charts in the past. May be able to work out something there.