# Recursive Algorithm for Tournament Brackets

Tags: php, recursion

I am creating a tournament bracket creation script, and I am getting stuck with tournaments with the number of players Non - Power of 2.  For instance, it is currently working great for 2, 4, 8, 16, 32,... etc.  But for 3, 5, 6, 7... I am stumped!

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
$numrows = 8; // Currently for Testing.
draw_bracket($numrows);

function draw_bracket($numplayers)
{
    draw_series_container();
    draw_bracket_layer($numplayers, 0);
    draw_series_container_end();
}

/* RECURSION, YO! */
function draw_bracket_layer($numplayers, $layer)
{
    $levels = floor(log($numplayers, 2));
    if ($layer == $levels - 1)
    {
        draw_player_box();
        draw_player_box();
    }
    else
    {
        draw_series_container();
            draw_bracket_layer($numplayers, $layer + 1);
        draw_series_container_end();

        draw_series_container();
            draw_bracket_layer($numplayers, $layer + 1);
        draw_series_container_end();
    }
}
```

I am assuming we need more 'base cases'.  Or perhaps more if statements for these off cases.

The functions draw_series_container() and draw_player_box are just filled with HTML code.  I can show them if we need to.

Could someone start me out with a bracket with 5 or 6 people?

Thanks!

Comment: please explain this formula: `$levels = floor(log($numplayers, 2));` - you really mean `natural logarithm`? Why count of levels depends on logarithm? Looks strange.

Comment: I got that from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294412/tournament-brackets-algorithm.  I am not exactly certain as to WHY it work... but testing up to 32 shows it does. :P

Answer (score 1):

Correct formula of levels is
    `$levels = intval(log($numplayers, 2))+1;`

Comment: with my current algo, + 1 prints too many players, as to - 1 prints the correct amount.  Perhaps there is something else I am doing wrong.