# How do i represent a tournament tree structure in a gridview for a windows store app (tree view is not available) using XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, treeview, windows-store-apps

I am currently implementing a tournament bracket drawer in a windows store app using **xaml/c#**. I had intended on using treeview and came up with some psuedo code for the tree view tournament and its nodes however once I began to implement this I quickly realized that treeviews are no longer allowed in windows store apps, making my work void. I am now intending to use gridview I am however confused as to how I am supposed to represent a hierarchical data structure such as a tree in a gridview. This example shows how to do it in asp.net, is this possible using XAML with a gridview?

[Tournament Brackets algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294412/tournament-brackets-algorithm)